How to edit a dockerfile to build image of db2，and when container start could init database and tables
How to edit a dockerfile to build  image of db2，and when container start could  init database and tables；
FROM ibmcom/db2:latest

COPY init.sql /home/db2inst1/
COPY init_db.sh /home/db2inst1/
ENV DB2INST1_PASSWORD=password
ENV LICENSE=accept


RUN chmod +x /home/db2inst1/init_db.sh


CMD ["/home/db2inst1/init_db.sh"]


# init_db.sh 
#!/bin/bash

su - db2inst1 -c "db2start"
su - db2inst1 -c "db2 -tvf /home/db2inst1/init.sql"

The Result is that the command "su - db2inst1 -c "db2 -tvf /home/db2inst1/init.sql"  " not effect

Did you follow the instructions at the end of the page https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2/ in the section "Build Your Own"?   Copying a shell script into the container directory /var/custom, and chmod +x that shell script should allow Db2 to run the script after the db2setup has completed.
